# C++ Update Function Argument

Tags: c++, function, parameters, pass-by-reference

I have a function defined with several parameters passed by value.  Both the function and inputs for the parameters depend on a common global variable.  I need some way to get my function to re-evaluate the inputs of its parameters while executing within its own scope.  Here is a simplified version of the code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int Sum(int arg1, int from, int to);
int i;
int func();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    Sum(func(), 0, 10);

    return 0;
}

int Sum(int arg1, int from, int to)
{
    int out = 0;
    for (i = from; i <= to; i++)
    {
        out += arg1;
        cout << "arg1 = " << arg1 << ", out = " << out << endl;
    }
    return out;
}

int func()
{
    return i;
}
```

Some highlights:
* Here I am trying to update the input values for parameter *arg1* on function Sum().

- Normally, I would solve this problem by defining the parameter by reference (in this case, the parameter is arg1 in function Sum).
- However, because the method in which I use this function normally involves combining multiple input values inline, I have to pass by value.

Is there some way to define a temporary unnamed function inline with the inputs for Sum?  Then I could pass parameters by reference and solve my troubles.  Or any other ideas for how to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a place you could use a function pointer.  Instead of passing `func()`, you pass simply `func`, and call it from within your function:

```
int Sum(int (*func_arg1)(void), int from, int to)
{
    int out = 0;
    for (i = from; i <= to; i++)
    {
        int arg1 = func_arg1();
        out += arg1;
        cout << "arg1 = " << arg1 << ", out = " << out << endl;
    }
    return out;
}
```

The syntax for function pointers is a bit unusual in C and C++.  The declaration `int (*func_arg1)(void)` declares a symbol named `func_arg1` that is a pointer to a function taking no arguments, but returning `int`.  In this case, that symbol is also the first argument of `Sum`.

The only other changes you need to make to your program are the prototype for `Sum` to match the function above, and to call `Sum` as follows:

```
Sum(func, 0, 10);
```

Comment: That has good potential.  One of the other things I want to do is be able to use multiple expressions as the input for Sum.  For example:  Sum(func() * i, 0, 10) instead of just Sum(func(), 0, 10).  If I understand correctly, this approach would not work for that.  I would need to find some way to wrap the multiple expressions into a single function.  Correct?

Comment: To get fancier than that, you should look into C++11 lambda expressions.  They give you the kind of flexibility I think you're looking for.